# Crypto Obfuscator showing exception, Could not resolve mscorlib

Tags: c#, wpf, obfuscation, crypto-obfuscator

While obfuscating my WPF C# application, it is showing Exception saying that

> Error occurred while obfuscation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException -
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve: mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e.
>   Specify the path where this assembly resides using 'Search
>   Directories' in the Crypto Obfuscator's Project Properties Dialog
>   (Ctrl+P).

I have also tried adding path to mscorlib.dll file in Search Directories Project Properties Dialog. but it is still showing same exception.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add directories in Search Directories Project Properties Dialog, **do not select**:

> Only allow same or higher versions when resolving referenced assemblies

Comment: Pappu, I have the same error, I integrate my WPF application with Crypto Obfuscator and adding paths to my dll files in Search Directories and uncheck the above .. When I press Obfuscate (F7) from Crypto Obfuscator does not get any error, but When I try to build my WPF Visual studio shows me the error. Can you help !

Answer (score 0):

When you add directories in Search Directories Project Properties Dialog, specify the search directory where the project reside.
because your DLL may be contain reference of other DLL s. i think it will solve your problem